# Searching all external drives in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to make an automator action where all external drives are searched for *.txt* files, which are then copied to a folder on the internal Macintosh HD drive.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to do this without having to specify each external drive's name each time, but that's a new one every time and not predictable. Is there any way for "indirectly" specifying the path to the external drives (I'm imagining something like a "pointer" to the USB-Ports)?

I know about the hidden */Volumes* folder, but then this would search all of Macintosh HD for *.txt* files as well, which is something I don't want...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any duplicate filenames being copied and if yes how do you want to handle the duplicates?

Comment: Yes duplicates will be copied each time a drive will be searched that already has been searched before, all .txt files that already where there can be replaced by the newer ones.

This is the setup I have so far (that works when I specify the drive name by editing the automator program each time before use):

- PAUSE
for 2 seconds
- FIND FINDER ITEMS
search [drive name]
all of the following are true:
File extension is .txt
- COPY FINDER ITEMS
To [destination folder], YES replace existing files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you mentioned **AppleScript**, however, this can be done so much easier and straight forward in **Terminal**.

You do not need to worry about the **Macintosh HD** in `/Volumes` as it's a *symbolic link* and `find` without the appropriate *option* is not going to traverse the *symbolic link*.

To use the following *example* **shell script** *code* in an **Automator** *workflow*, simple add a **Run Shell Script** *action*, adding the following line of *code* while changing `'/path/to/destination'` to the *directory* the *files* are to be copied to.

```
find /Volumes -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -I '{}' -0 cp -a '{}' '/path/to/destination'
```

This will find all the **.txt** *files* on external disks and copy them to the *destination* while overwriting existing *files* in the *destination*.

That's it, all done just a single *action* in the *workflow* is all that's needed.

Also, if you run this with no external disks attached, not to worry as it will essentially do nothing.

---

**Notes:**

If for some reason you need to use a **Run AppleScript** *action*, you can still use the *example* **shell script** *code* using the `do shell script` *command* of **AppleScript**, e.g.:

```
do shell script "find /Volumes -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -I '{}' -0 cp -a '{}' '/path/to/destination'"
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can avoid piping to `xargs` with just this…
`find /Volumes -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec cp {} /path/to/destination/ \;`

Comment: @wch1zpink, Yes, you can use `-exec`, but it's my understanding it's more safe to use a _NUL_ terminated _string_, hence the use of `-print0` in the `find` _command_ and the use of `xargs`.

Comment: Thank you so much @user3439894!
This works, and it really is a very straightforward approach, I like it!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to consider the point user3439894 raised about duplicates. Until then, try this:

- Run Applescript (See below for its contents)
- Copy Finder Items (Select your destination and whether it will replace files)

As for the script, this should replace the **entire contents** of the 'run applescript' text box. Please note that there is no error handling here. You will likely get an error if you run this without an external drive attached.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set drList to POSIX path of disks 4 thru -1
end tell
set afList to {}
repeat with dr in drList
    copy (do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & dr & "  kMDItemContentType=\"public.plain-text\"") to end of afList
end repeat
tell application "Finder"
    set bfList to {}
    repeat with w in paragraphs of item 1 of afList
        set x to w as text
        set y to POSIX file x as alias
        copy y to end of bfList
    end repeat
end tell
bfList
```

Notes:
The system events block generates a list of extra disks. Note the first three results when you run this:

```
tell application "System Events" to POSIX path of disks
--> {"/", "/home", "/net", "/Volumes/xdisk1", "/Volumes/xdisk2"}
```

The applescript then runs a shell script that cycles through the found disks 'dr' and searches for plain text files. The resulting 'afList' is passed off to the Finder, which converts it into a list of aliases 'bfList' to pass on to the copy action. As it searches with mdfind, any folders set to not be searched will not be searched.

bfList will resemble this:

```
{alias "xdisk1:for cleanup:Various.txt, alias "xdisk1:OtherVideo_archive:Lecture Series:lecture.06.txt", alias "xdisk2:for cleanup:Reservation notes.txt}
```

There are a variety of ways to perform this task but this one is relatively straightforward which should make it simple to change the file type or the copy destination.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try!
The script should never run without an external drive attached because it will be run automatically by an application that handles backups (the .txt files are transfer logs of backups), so that's not a problem. Also the folders where these transfer logs are generated are never in a folder thats set to not be searched, so thats not a problem as well!
Basically I just need a workaround for the software thats generating the transfer logs always on the external drives without a possibility to select a different destination on the internal drive...

Comment: You could add error handling so that the workflow handles the no drive issue gracefully, but for now it would just give you an error. If these log files have any other common features (e.g. some word that's always in the name, or they are in a similarly named folder, etc…) then you can tweak the script to take that into account.

Comment: Hi! I tried this script, but I always get the following syntax error:
*Failed to create query for '1 kMDItemContentType=public.plain-text'.*

Comment: What happens if you run this in the terminal: `mdfind -onlyin /Volumes/xdisk1 kMDItemContentType="public.plain-text"` (with of course, an actual drive name there). Basically, the do shell script line builds that command and runs it.